# How to make VHDL output signal stateless

Tags: state, signals, vhdl

I have the following code which is a part of my digital clock:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

-- Seconds counter
entity SecCounter is
    port( 
            s_enable: in std_logic;
            s_load: in std_logic; -- When high, sets this counter to the value in the     data inputs
            s_clk: in std_logic; -- Clock
            s_input: in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0); -- Data inputs
            s_output: out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0); --Outputs
            s_wrap: out std_logic
        );
    end SecCounter;

architecture imp of SecCounter is
    -- Intermediate signal to mainpulate the seconds as integer
    signal sec: integer range 0 to 60 := 22;

    begin
        s_output <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(sec,6)); -- Assign the input to the binary     value of sec

        process(s_clk, s_load, s_enable) -- If clk, enable, or load is changed
        begin
            s_wrap <= '0'; -- Clear the wrap

            if (s_enable = '0' and s_load = '1') then -- Set the clock
                sec <= to_integer(unsigned(s_input));
            elsif (s_enable = '1' and rising_edge(s_clk)) then -- Increment the counter
                sec <= sec + 1;
            end if;

            if sec = 60 then -- Restart counter and toggle the next counter
                sec <= 0;
                s_wrap <= '1';
            end if;
        end process;
end imp;
```

s_wrap acts as an enable to the next counter. What I'm trying to do is that if this counter equals 60 I want to enable the next counter for a single clock edge. I'm trying to do this through setting s_wrap to true and then to false in the next clock edge; however, it doesn't change. Is there a way to make is_wrap stateless? IF not, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You're using `ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all`, which is has several problems. Moreover it conflicts with `numeric_std`, which you are also using. Just remove the `std_logic_unsigned` use clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning values to sec outside of the rising_edge(clk) clause. And you are not assigning anything to sec if s_enable=0 and s_load=0. Either of those facts make sec an asynchronous signal. If you fix both then the described problem should go away.

And Oli Charlesworth has a good point about checking for 59 rather than 60. Then you do not have to artificially include the non-existent 60 in your range either. And initializing sec to a value is not meaningful. You should initialize it in your reset clause.

You may have other problems since you are reading s_enable, s_load and s_input asynchronously. That is normally done only for the reset signal.

Comment: Point of correction: Initialization of signals **is meaningful**, provided there is support from your synthesis tools. I recommend initializing signals when declared and not use a reset, especially if a reset is not otherwise needed. This can lead to better logic utilization during map and P&R. In the world of Xilinx parts, on device configuration/boot, all FFs have a known state which can be configured using signal initialization. Search for "initialization" in this reference: http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_1/xst_v6s6.pdf

Answer (score 1):

*[Disclaimer: I'm not great with VHDL, so I can't advise on syntax.]*

I think you want to assert `s_wrap` when `sec` reaches *59*, not *60*.  That way, on the next clock edge, the minutes counter will see `s_wrap = 1` and increment, at the same time that this counter output becomes 0 again.

I *think* you want something like this:

```
process(s_clk, s_load, s_enable) -- If clk, enable, or load is changed
begin

    if (s_enable = '0' and s_load = '1') then -- Set the clock
        sec <= to_integer(unsigned(s_input));
    elsif (s_wrap = '1') then -- Wrap
        sec <= 0;
    elsif (s_enable = '1' and rising_edge(s_clk)) then -- Increment the counter
        sec <= sec + 1;
    end if;

end process;

s_wrap <= '1' when sec = 59 else '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do would be to declare sec as a variable in the process, as variables update immediately:

```
process(s_clk, s_load, s_enable)
variable v_sec : integer range 0 to 60;
begin
if reset = '1' then
    v_sec := 0;
    s_sec <= (others => '0');
    s_wrap <= '0';
elsif rising_edge(s_clk) then
   s_output <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(v_sec,6));
   if s_enable = '1' then
     v_sec := v_sec +1;
     if v_sec = 60 then
        v_sec:= 0;
        s_wrap <= '1';
     else
        s_wrap <= '0';
     end if;
   else
   s_wrap <= '0';
   end if;
end if;
```

If you simulate this in modelsim, sec will go 0,1,2,....58,59,0,1,2, and s_wrap will equal 1 everytime sec is equal to 0, except for the first time, when the reset condition sets it to 0.